# How do I make Mozilla Thunderbird close the composed email window as soon as I hit send?

Tags: thunderbird, windows-live-mail

When I hit send in Windows Live Mail, the email window would close immediately, and the work of sending the email would be done in the background and mentioned only in the progress bar at the bottom of the window.

How do make Mozilla Thunderbird behave in the same way? I obviously don't want to wait while the application does all the background communicating with the email server work before seeing the window close so I can get back to other tasks.

Version is 45.8.0 (latest).

Comment: Independently of the behavior of the window you **can** go back to other tasks. Sending of the e-mail is done in background, as you can write another mail or do other stuff. Just ignore when the window closes and work along.

Comment: Then I have to Alt-Tab out. It's just a wrong design and I want to change it if possible. Best solution is just to buy Microsoft Outlook but that's about $100.

Answer (score 1):

Settings > General Config Editor (at the bottom of list) > Set `mailnews.sendInBackground` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options → Advanced → Conf Editor. Set 'Send in Background' to true.